# Arithmetic Overflow on numeric AVG() SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, average

Why does

```
select avg(cast(5 as numeric(15,2)))
```

returns "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."?

Documentation states the following about the avg function:

> input: decimal category (p, s)
>
> output: decimal(38, s) divided by
>   decimal(10, 0)

I don't really see how it would overflow.

Comment: works for me on sql server 2008

Comment: here is the link for BOL  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Comment: Can you help me understand the purpose of using `avg` function in this example?

Comment: Is this the whole query?

Comment: The only purpose of the query is to show the problem. BTW, running SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @JKonrad - We really need something vaguely reproducible in order to help.

Comment: I just had 2 people verify this and it works on sql server 2005

Comment: That's exactly how the problem happens, anyway, it seems to be when I'm querying a specific database, maybe some configuration settings?

Comment: Are you sure you are running this on SQL Server and not Sybase or Oracle?

Comment: Works on SQL Server 2000 as well. You're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem:

Database Properties > Options > Numeric Round-Abort was ON.

When set to off the query executed with success.